# Translate certain parts of the page only with Bing translator web widget

Tags: javascript, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api, web-widget

Our website is offered in 10 different languages with all static content already translated by external vendors. We have a requirement to translate certain parts of the page we do not have in advance.

The Translator Widget from Bing looks good except that it translates the whole page instead of only certain parts of the page. As a POC, I tried loading the [translation API code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341983.aspx) in a hidden iframe, set the text to translate in a div element, and then called the [Translate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341982.aspx) and it worked. I was able to extract the translation and use it in my web page.

I would like to know if this kind of use is allowed or am I required to create an API account with BING or show some message somewhere in my page that a part of the content was translated by BING, since the translator widget is hidden inside the iframe?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on MSDN for the Translate API of the widget, you can exclude elements from being translated by setting the custom attribute 'translate=no'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341982.aspx

Comment: If I want to translate just one paragraph in my page which has several paragraphs of texts, it won't make sense to add 'translate=no' attribute to the rest of the DOM elements.

Comment: I ended up calling Microsoft Translator API [link] (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx). It supports translation of upto 2M characters free of cost.